# Wrap with abbreviation for ERB

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, erb, ruby-on-rails-5, code-snippets

I love Emmet's Wrap With Abbreviation [(docs)](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/).

It lets me quickly create a html list from a regular list

start:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

command:

```
ul>li*
```

result:

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>
```

I really want to be able to do the same with with ERB tags

start:

```
link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user
micropost.content
time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at)
```

command:

```
???
```

end:

```
<%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %>
<%= micropost.content %>
<%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %>
```

Is this possible?

Currently I'm using erb snippets and it's awful to have to focus on my erb line by line.

I want to focus on just my ruby all the way, then focus on the erb tags, then focus on the html tags, then focus on the html classes/ids.

I found a great [snippet](https://gist.github.com/kenzie/2788689) that lets me wrap individual lines, however if If I try it with multiple lines I get:

start:

```
user.cats
user.dogs
```

command:

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
<%= ${0:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT} %>
]]></content>
  <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
  <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
  <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
  <!-- <scope>source.erb</scope> -->
    <description>ERB: Wrap with =</description>
</snippet>
```

result:

```
<%= user.cats
user.dogs %>
```

But I'd like to get

```
<%= user.cat %>
<%= user.dogs %>
```

Would love some help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get this to do what you want is to split your selection into multiple lines using `Selection > Split Into Lines` (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+L</kbd> on Windows/Linux). Once you do that when you invoke the snippet it will operate on each selection individually.

[image: Sample session]